# Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Projects - Web Setup Project and IIS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, setup-deployment, web-setup-project

I am creating a Web Setup Project using **Visual Studio 2013** to create a `MSI` installer for an `ASP.NET Web API` project.  I am using [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d) extension from Microsoft that brings these projects into VS2013.

I am trying to understand what the `Web Setup Project` does in relation to `IIS`.  It appears there is no difference between a `Web Setup Project` and the standard Windows `Setup Project` in what it actually does.  They both install the files to a directory that I choose during installation.  I would expect the `Web Setup Project` to create a site/virtual directory in IIS but it's not.  It doesn't do anything different than if I use a windows Setup Project.

Is there something else I need to do to make the Web Setup Project install a site/virtual directory to IIS?  Or is the correct behavior to just install the files to a directory and that's it?

There is no documentation for the VS2013 version of this but I am looking at the reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wx3b589t(v=vs.100).aspx) for VS2010 and the product appears about the same